# update wpf UI label before running pearl script

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to update the label contents and then run an pearl script (which just restarts the services).
Here is my code

```
private Process p = new Process();
    private void NextBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // update label
      this.lblmsg.Content = "Hello World!!";
      // run pearl script


        Assembly osInterfaceAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(ActivateConfigurationConstants.osInterfaceAssemblyName);
        Type logicalType = osInterfaceAssembly.GetType(ActivateConfigurationConstants.logical);
        MethodInfo logicalMethInfo = null;
        logicalMethInfo = logicalType.GetMethod(ActivateConfigurationConstants.logicalTranslateLastItem, new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        string gyroComDir = logicalMethInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { ActivateConfigurationConstants.gyrocomdir }).ToString();

        string arg = string.Format("\"{0}activate_configuration.pl\"", gyroComDir);
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("perl.exe", arg + " BATCH");
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        p.StartInfo = processInfo;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();



    }
```

but on the UI first the script is run then the label is updated. Can I do the reverse of this, first update the label and then run the script

Answer (score 2):

You should never wait inside the GUI thread (which is effective in the button click event handler).

Use something like `BackgroundWorker`, `ThreadPool` or `Task` to wait in the background:

```
Task.Run(()=> {
Console.WriteLine ("start and wait for the external process");
});
```

Such the GUI thread can finish the button click event and update the label.

Comment: Then you did it wrong - hard to say why it fails without the corresponding snippet of code.

Comment: Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.lblmsg.Content = "Hello World!!"));

Comment: BackgroundWorker workerThread;
workerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
workerThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(workerThread_DoWork);
void workerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                this.lblActivateConfig.Content = "Assigning text by background thread..";
                
                
             }));
}
private void NextBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 workerThread.RunWorkerAsync();
}

Comment: It's better to add this, kind of formatted, to the question. Nevertheless, I had a look into this snippet. Where's the call to the external process? As it stands, the backgroundworker does nothing else than delegating the call to update the label back to the GUI thread.

Comment: p.Start();
p.WaitForExit(); where p is an object of process class. In these lines am starting the script

Comment: I'm sorry - I still can't see where you try to start process and update label from `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the fix for the problem, using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem i was able to fix the problem..